# Where gorilla session values are stored?

Tags: go, gorilla

I am using gorilla session package to manage the sessions of a website.

For the signin process my idea is add the user info to the session values. So each next request made with the same session will be authenticated with the user info.

If I am not wrong, I think this is correct, because the session itself sent as a cookie to the client, does not contain the values encrypted in his body. Instead the cookie value is just the key to get the full session values stored on he server side.

So, my question is:

Are the related session data saved at server side? Or the all the related session info is saved encrypted on the session value sent through cookies to the client?

Thanks

Comment: depends on the backend storage you actually configured.

Comment: @mh-cbon Oh I see, I am using CookieStore. So if I change for example to pg store, al the values would be saved on db instead of cookie?

Comment: that is correct.